# How to avoid HTML IDs conflicts when adding to DOM of 3rd party pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

When adding extra HTML elements to a web page using Javascript / jQuery and adding extra external CSS declarations to go with them, you need to prevent the IDs of these element's and the CSS class names conflicting with those already on the page. e.g. you could already have an ID like "outerWrapper" or "nav" somewhere on the page, and the new content may also have IDs named the same.

When creating code to be added to your own web pages it is relatively easy.

But if you want to provide code that can be used on any 3rd party website, you have no control over what IDs and class names are already in use on the page, and even less over what changes may be made to the page in the future.

So what is the best practice for avoiding these conflicts when dealing with code for 3rd party use?

Up to now, we've been simply using iframes, but that's not ideal.

CSS child selectors can prevent our added CSS affecting existing elements / classes, but they won't prevent our new elements getting styled by CSS that was already on the page.

Is prefixing all the IDs of our added content, say with a company, product name or container name, the only way forward? e.g. the video player JWPlayer prefixes the container name to all the element IDs for its HTML5 player.

I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: IMO, prefixing your class names (and especially your IDs) with a namespace of some sort (company, product, etc.) is a good solution when your content has a good chance of being mixed in with other content over which you have no control.

Answer (score 2):

This has been a challenge for me also, especially because the app I'm working on consists of a lot of jquery popups/dialogs that contain form fields with input ID's the same as form fields on the parent part of the page.

Things that I've found that solve this in a satisfactory manner:

1. Rely on a server side generation of HTML inputs (I created my own class for this). This will give you the freedom to "prefix" your HTML input ID's easily.
2. Use ONLY camelCase in everything you do. When you are in a situation that requires prefixing to avoid naming collisions, then you can use an underscore to show separation of what part of the name is prefix and what part is not. The underscore will now have a direct purpose in your app, so that you can easily write functionality to strip the prefix off when you need to.
3. Create the prefixes using a consistent naming convention. I personally grab the class name of the backend service class where the inputs are coming from (not to be confused with the class you reuse to generate them, mentioned in #1) and use that as the prefix. For example, `blogUsers_firstName` and `blogUsers_lastName` and `blogUsers_email` are all HTML text inputs that come from a server side class called `class blogUsers { }`.
4. Strip the prefixes when you do things like make ajax calls, so that you are receiving the inputs into your server side controller classes without the prefix on them (since you are now server-side and you don't have name collisions). This makes life a lot easier and clearer on the  server side.
5. For more public front-end website situations where you are more likely to contain your inputs inside a `<form>` tag and will probably implement *progressive enhancement / graceful degradation* (ie. a jquery click binding on the submit button with event.preventDefault), then don't worry...just make sure your server-side generation ONLY adds the prefix to the ID and not the NAME of the input. Regular old form submissions use `name` when sending the data, so keep this free of prefixing and you'll be fine for those imaginary paranoid folks who have turned off javascript.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use a GUID to generate an ID when the DOM object is created dynamically.  The downfall is that the ID will not use user friendly (as it is just a list of randomly generated characters).  Check out this thread: [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Another option is create your own naming convention, similar to what ASP.Net does.  The control can have a static name (like 'myControl') but gets a list of all parent objects pre-pended to it.  It would be up to the user to ensure that they follow good HTML practives and provide id's to their elements.  So, if your generated controls was nested in a table, within a div, your new ID might be something like: myTable_myDiv_myControl.